# Moxiemanager: file_get_contents() when uploading images

Tags: php, tinymce, moxiemanager

we use MoxiManager plugin in TinyMCE to upload images in our PHP web app, we noticed a error when uploading images in the TinyMCE editor:

file_get_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory

```
Stacktrace:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Util/IniParser.php:23
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Util/IniParser.php:23
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Vfs/Local/FileConfigProvider.php:63
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Vfs/BaseFile.php:313
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Commands/BaseCommand.php:146
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Commands/ListRootsCommand.php:42
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/CommandCollection.php:39
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/CorePlugin.php:69
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/Handlers/JsonRpcHandler.php:74
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/classes/CorePlugin.php:82
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/www/vendors/tinymce/plugins/moxie/api.php:18
```

Which is:

```
/**
 * Loads and parses the specified file by path.
 *
 * @param string $path File path to ini file to parse.
 */
public function load($path) {
    return $this->parse(file_get_contents($path));
}
```

But I don't want to mess around with it

Maybe we've got the filesystem rootpath wrong.

```
$moxieManagerConfig['filesystem.rootpath'] = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news-web/data/articles/images';
```

The images are avaliable on:

http://localhost:8888/news-web/data/articles/images/image.jpg

Or maybe some read/write permission are missing to the folder, but have that checked.

Can someone please give me a hint?

Thank you

Comment: Probably it is your case. Could you check?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542374/error-file-get-contents-read-of-8192-bytes-failed-with-errno-21

Comment: I'm afraid thats not the case, but I've corrected the file path specified in another config and it works. Now I need to check that up on the production server. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify the public folder of the website in another MoxieManager config, namely FileConfigProvider.php. Now it seems to works.