# Why am I getting error no 21 when I generate a pdf using mpdf library in PHP, in live server?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, mpdf

I am using `mPDF` library to generate a pdf from my `php` server script. I have used `composer` to install the library into my **live** server file system.

I was being able to generate the `pdf` file successfully for quite a couple of months, until today morning. Everytime I try to generate the pdf it shows this error in the console:

> **Notice**:  file_get_contents(): Read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in **/home/user/domains/report_generation/backend_pdfgen/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/File/LocalContentLoader.php** on line **10**

According to the console, I went to line **10** in **LocalContentLoader.php**. This is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Mpdf\File;

class LocalContentLoader implements \Mpdf\File\LocalContentLoaderInterface
{

    public function load($path)
    {
        return file_get_contents($path);
    }

}
```

This is my **pdf** generation script (**pdfgen.php**):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['setAutoTopMargin' => 'stretch']);
    $mpdf->SetTitle("report.pdf");
    $mpdf->SetAuthor("Anonymous");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="text-align:center";>Some data here</div>');
    $mpdf->Output("reports/report.pdf");
?>
```

My `file hierarchy`:

[image]

I am not being able to understand what's wrong with it. I surfed on the internet and found a post where it was mentioned that I have to increase the `upload_max_filesize`, it's already increased to 1 GB, but still the error message shows. Where am I going wrong. Please guide me.

Surprisingly, the error doesn't show when I run the script in my **localhost server**.

Comment: No, but I think it's because of  **insufficient disk space**, because when I run the server script in my **localhost** server, then it works!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error file\_get\_contents(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542374/error-file-get-contents-read-of-8192-bytes-failed-with-errno-21)

Answer (score 0):

This is very likeley because of **insufficient disk space**.

Try another location or verify you have enough space. Check where `report.pdf` is intended to be safed.